# split array php from mysql

Tags: php, arrays, split

i have array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [question_id] => 13
            [is_break] => 0
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [question_id] => 14
            [is_break] => 1
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [question_id] => 15
            [is_break] => 0
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [question_id] => 16
            [is_break] => 1
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [question_id] => 17
            [is_break] => 1
        )
)
```

how to split by `is_break = 1`, so i have `question_id (13,14)(15,16)(17)`
so i have 3 array that array [0] consist of question_id 13 and 14 array [1] consist of question_id 15 and 16 and array [2] consist of question_id 17

Comment: Please clear the question. You mean split by value of is_break? If so then your final result is wrong.

Comment: so i have 3 array that array [0] consist of question_id 13 and 14 array [1] consist of question_id 15 and 16 and array [2] consist of question_id 17

Comment: In my answer you will get an array of n elements whose `is_break=1`. array[0] contain first element, array[1] second element and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

```
$count = 0;
$result = array();
foreach($array as $a) {
    $result[$count][] = $a['question_id'];
    if($a['is_break']) {
        $count++;
    }
}
```

See **[Codepad](http://codepad.org/izSgSGjI)**.

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this.. [**FYI** : *This works on PHP >= 5.5* ]

```
$new_array = array_chunk(array_column($your_array,'question_id'),2);
var_dump($new_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$questions = array();

foreach ($main_array as $subarray) {
   if($subarray['is_break'] == 1) {
       array_push($questions, $subarray['question_id']);
   }
}
```

Now `$questions` array has the question ids.

Comment: This will only return `question_id` having `is_break = 1`.

Comment: In question i see the question owner wants to get ids where `is_break = 1`